# How to access a property from belongs_to model from a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models in my app: Person and Review each person has many reviews and each review belongs to a person. I have an attribute called `grade` inside of my review model and I'd like to display the average grade of each person so I wrote this scope:

```
scope :average_grade, -> { self.first.review.average(:grade) }
```

Is there a better way for doing that? Besides the 2 queries that this method needs, I also have to run another 2 queries to get the proper Person object in my controller:

```
def show
  @average = Person.includes(:review).where(id: params[:id]).average_grade
  @person =  Person.includes(:review).find(params[:id])
end
```

How could I avoid all of those queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scope is an instance method rather than scope, since it does not return ActiveRecord::Relation object.

I suggest you to do following:

```
# person.rb:
def average_grade
  review.average(:grade)
end

# controller:
def show
  @person =  Person.find(params[:id])
  @average = @person.average_grade
end
```

Comment: Thank you!By the way why the method doesn't need self?

Comment: cause `self` inside instance method can be omitted if method calls on instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
# person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

# review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person

  scope :by_person, ->(person) { where(person_id: person) }
end

# persons_controller
class PersonsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :person

private

  def person
    return @person if defined? @person

    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end
end

# show.html.haml
- present(person) do |person_presenter|
  %p= person_presenter.average_grade

# person_presenter.rb
class PersonPresenter < BasePresenter
  present :person

  def average_grade
    Review.by_person(person).average(:grade)
  end
end
```

More on presenters you could find here [Railscasts PRO #287 Presenters from Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U)